# Como usar a função click() com uma toast

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize

Fiz um sistema que quando o usuário entra na index é exibido uma toast do materialize, preciso que quando o usuario click nela ele seja redireciona a outra pagina, tentei fazer da seguinte forma mas não tive sucesso;

```
<script>
    Materialize.toast('Você tem '+retorno+' novas notificação de serviço'+'<div class="material-icons" id="kol">info_outline</div>', 4500, 'blue rounded');

    $( ".rounded" ).click(function() {
      alert( "teste" );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tente com: `$(document).on("click", ".rounded", function() {
      alert( "teste" );
    });`

Comment: funcionou, muito obrigado

Comment: você sabe me dizer por que o meu código não funcionou ?

Comment: Elementos adicionados de forma dinâmica usa uma sintaxe diferente, como comentei acima.